# Angular expression evaluate equal to

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to make something like this.

```
<h3 ng-show="{{mode == 'create'}}">Create Vacancy</h3>
<h3 ng-show="{{mode == 'edit'}}">Edit this Vacancy</h3>
```

Where `$scope.mode` is either "create" or "edit".

How do I do this? Nothing I'm trying is working.

Comment: Have you tried without the double curly braces? I.e., ng-show="mode == 'create'"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ng-show` evals expression itself, so don't use interpolated text.  Update your code to:

```
<h3 ng-show="mode == 'create'">Create Vacancy</h3>
<h3 ng-show="mode == 'edit'">Edit this Vacancy</h3>
```

Comment: Sweet.. that worked thanks! Also got it working with ng-switch. But much easier like this.